# Dynamic JS image isn't being loaded in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am pulling in a JS file from  like this:

```
<script>
 //<![CDATA[
 (function() {
  function asyncLoad() {
    var urls = ["https://www.domain.com/tracker/script_tag/?shop=dev"];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = urls[i];
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
  }
  window.attachEvent ? window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad) : window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
})();

//]]>
</script>
```

In this script_tag/ JS file, I have this:

```
var image = new Image(); 
document.body.appendChild(image);
image.src = "https://www.domain.com/tracker/image?shop=dev&i=NULL&sci="+getCookie('cart');
image.setAttribute('style', 'float: right;');
```

The problem is that this code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. I've been doing most of my testing in IE 10 and it seems to just ignore this JS. I do not think it is a caching issue since the getCookie('cart') parameter changes all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: hit F12 to see console errors

Comment: @mplungjan I did. It shows nothing about this.

Comment: @AlexMarkov "*nothing about this*" Are there other errors occurring? An error in one segment of code can disrupt other segments, especially syntax errors.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I see one error in there, but I believe it has to do with the social media (FB) buttons:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 <script src="<insert name here>.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

instead of the script tag and

```
 var urls = ["https://www.domain.com/tracker/script_tag/?shop=dev"];
 for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
   var image = new Image(); 
 image.src = "https://www.domain.com/tracker/image?shop=dev&i=NULL&sci="+getCookie('cart');
 image.setAttribute('style', 'float: right;');
 document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

in the file

Comment: Tried this, but no luck. :-(

Comment: I can't use the <script> alternative, because my JS needs to be loaded through that first sync function. The only thing that I can change is the script_tag/ JS file. I ran the other code and it doesn't seem to have worked. Here it is in the console: http://cl.ly/image/1s0F1N3H332b It looks like it runs, but it doesn't actually run the pixel.